# Printing out variables in c changes values of variables

Tags: c, matrix, printf

I have an odd problem with some c-programme here. I was getting some wrong values in a matrix I was finding the determinant of and so I started printing variables - yet found that by printing values out the actual values in the code changed.

I eventually narrowed it down to one specific `printf` statement - highlighted in the code below. If I comment out this line then I start getting incorrect values in my determinent calculations, yet by printing it out I get the value out I expect

Code below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUMBER 15

double determinant_calculation(int size, double array[NUMBER][NUMBER]);

int main() {
    double array[NUMBER][NUMBER], determinant_value;
    int size;

    array[0][0]=1;
    array[0][1]=2;
    array[0][2]=3;
    array[1][0]=4;
    array[1][1]=5;
    array[1][2]=6;
    array[2][0]=7;
    array[2][1]=8;
    array[2][2]=10;

    size=3;

    determinant_value=determinant_calculation(size, array);
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\nDeterminant value is %lf \n\n\n\n\n\n", determinant_value);
    return 0;
}

double determinant_calculation(int size, double array[NUMBER][NUMBER])
{
    double determinant_matrix[NUMBER][NUMBER], determinant_value;
    int x, y, count=0, sign=1, i, j;


    /*initialises the array*/
    for (i=0; i<(NUMBER); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<(NUMBER); j++)
        {
            determinant_matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    /*does the re-cursion method*/
    for (count=0; count<size; count++)
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<size; j++)
            {
                if (i!=0&&j!=count)
                {
                    determinant_matrix[x][y]=array[i][j];
                    if (y<(size-2)) {
                        y++;
                    } else {
                        y=0;
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //commenting this for loop out changes the values of the code determinent prints -7 when commented out and -3 (expected) when included!
        for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<size; j++){
                printf("%lf ", determinant_matrix[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        if(size>2) {
            determinant_value+=sign*(array[0][count]*determinant_calculation(size-1 ,determinant_matrix));
        } else {
            determinant_value+=sign*(array[0][count]*determinant_matrix[0][0]);
        }
        sign=-1*sign;
    }
    return (determinant_value);
}
```

I know its not the prettiest (or best way) of doing what I'm doing with this code but it's what I've been given - so can't make huge changes. I don't suppose anyone could explain why printing out the variables can actually change the values? or how to fix it because ideally i don't want to!!

Comment: why not give a self-contained program so somebody could recreate the result and then debug it? help someone help you

Comment: The determinant of that matrix is -3, not -1.

Comment: Your variable determinant_value is not initialized.

Comment: @ylc thankyou!! if you put that as an answer will accept it. Out of interest why did printing out the matrix rectify this though?? Because I tried several matricies and none of them worked without that printf line (for obvious reasons now) but they all did when the matrix was printed out with that printf line.

Comment: @interjay thankyou - was just a typo though :) Was giving -7 - obviously was wrong

Comment: Okay I'll post the revision with a test case.

Comment: We can only speculate since its undefined behavior, but most likely declaring the constant strings `"\n"` and `"%lf "` shifted around the memory location of `determinant_value` in such a way that it happened to be `0`, but before it was pointing at a memory location that happened to be `-4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable determinant_value is not initialized as 0, so that causes problems.
Here is the revised version with the test case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER 3

double determinant_calculation(int size, double array[NUMBER][NUMBER])
{
    double determinant_matrix[NUMBER][NUMBER], determinant_value = 0;
    int x, y, count=0, sign=1, i, j;

    /*initialises the array*/
    for (i=0; i<(NUMBER); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<(NUMBER); j++)
        {
            determinant_matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    /*does the re-cursion method*/
    for (count=0; count<size; count++)
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<size; j++)
            {
                if (i!=0&&j!=count)
                {
                    determinant_matrix[x][y]=array[i][j];
                    if (y<(size-2)) {
                        y++;
                    } else {
                        y=0;
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(size>2) {
            determinant_value+=sign*(array[0][count]*determinant_calculation(size-1,determinant_matrix));
        } else {
            determinant_value+=sign*(array[0][count]*determinant_matrix[0][0]);
        }
        sign=-1*sign;
    }
    return (determinant_value);
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    double ans;
    double array[NUMBER][NUMBER] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,10}};

    ans = determinant_calculation(3, array);

    printf("the matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUMBER; ++j) {
                printf("%lf ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("determinant : %lf\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output would be:

```
the matrix
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 
4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 
7.000000 8.000000 10.000000 
determinant : -3.000000
```

But I have no idea for your second question in the comments.